# Why does my Netlify html form work, but not redirect to a confirmation page?

Tags: html, hugo, netlify

I'm working on a Hugo based website, that I am deploying with Netlify. I would like to include a form using Netlify's form support ([docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/)).

My form looks like this:

```html
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" data-netlify="true" method="post" role="form" action="{{ .URL }}formsuccess">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea rows="6" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="cf-submit">
    <button type="submit" id="contact-submit" class="btn btn-transparent">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now, this form does work. But Netlify says that you can specify the action attribute to create a link for the submit button. This is the part that I can't get to work: I stay on the form page, and can click submit infinitely (submitting the form again and again).

- I have entered the path of my action attribute in a simple anchor, and there it does work.
- I have also tried without the action attribute. According to the docs, this should link to a generic confirmation page, but this doesn't work for me either.

How can I redirect my users to a confirmation page after submitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Netlify's support team I figured out the problem.

The action path needs to be an actual path. In my case, it needs to be in the site's public directory. I was trying to make it work with a URL with a suffix (example.com/en/pathname) or with a partial html (like many Hugo templates use). This is not possible.

When you have put in an action path, you can not use Netlify's default one anymore, because:

> (Netlify's) "system stores your action path in our database and will
>   continue to use it until you override it with another action path."

Comment: Hi Jabok, the netlify form page example has button is that not correct? https://docs.netlify.com/forms/setup/#html-forms

Comment: It's been a while, but I think that the problem was something else, and the element didn't affect the submit. I will update the solution, don't want to put false information out there without having confirmed it.

Answer (score 0):

> The path must be relative to the site root, starting with a `/`.

Make sure the code in your static site generator is resolving to the above rule.

`action="{{ .URL }}formsuccess"`

needs to look similar to:

`action="/path/to/formsuccess"`

Comment: Hugo converts {{ .URL }} to the site root, which I can also see in my devtools. Changing it to /formsuccess doesn't change anything.

Comment: netlify's form handling does require a path starting with / rather than a URL, so @talves' advice is correct.  Something else seems to be wrong and the helpdesk (support@netlify.com) would be happy to take a look next week when the office reopens and advise if you link us (I work there) your form.

Comment: Thank you, I have sent an email and will report back if I have a working solution!